# How to send data to join table with many-to-many relationship in DynamoDB / AWS Amplify / React via GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, e-commerce, aws-amplify

Extremely new to React. Project in school to create a full-stack application (creating an e-commerce app in React). I have built the shopping cart functionality and is working but I am struggling with sending data to DynamoDB via GraphQL API. I have a many-to-many relationship (many games to many orders) and my DynamoDB has the Game table, the Order table, and the GameOrder (join) table. This is my current logic and I am unsure what the issue is, or if there is a better way of doing this.

1. Loop through the cart items (games)
2. Query the Game table and loop through the games in the table
3. If (game ID in cart === game ID in Game table){
   This is the game the customer is ordering so Save "order" in the Order table with the game ID's       being ordered.
   }
4. Send Game ID from Game table and Order ID from Order table to the GameOrder (join) table to tie the two together.

I am able to get data to the Order table but I do not see any column / attribute for the game ID's attached. When I grab the code AWS Amplify provides, it makes it appear that there is a game attribute but when I look at the Order table, there is no game attribute. Do I add the game ID to games: [] when I send the data to the Order table? This is the code AWS Amplify provided:

```
await DataStore.save(
    new Order({
        "customerName": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "customerAddress": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        **"games": []**
    })
);
```

In my below code, I have put the ID of the game in the Games table as games: [gameID], but when I look at the Order table, as there is no game attribute, and therefore I do not see that data reflected in the Order table. Am I supposed to leave that blank, just as games: [] ? The Game and Order table do not have any relation, correct? As the join table has the relation to both of them. So the order in the Order table doesn't need to know what games are assigned to the order? This occurs in the join table? Is that correct? Also, when I send the new order to the Order table, how do I grab that order ID to send to the GameOrder table? Do I need to save order to Order table, and then query the Order table? Or can I set my own ID's so I don't need to query to get the ID? Being that the partition keys in the join table is GameID and OrderID, is that what I need to send to the join table? That is what I was trying to do, to no avail.

```
<Button variant="success" onClick={checkout}>
                                Complete purchase!
                            </Button>

const NavbarComponent = () => {
    const cart = useContext(CartContext);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const checkout = async () => {
        // loop through games in cart
        for (let item of cart.items) {
            // save the ID of each game
            const cartGameId = JSON.stringify(item["id"])
            // query the Game DB
            const games = await DataStore.query(Game);

            // inner loop - loop through games in Game DB
            for (let game of games) {
                const dbGameId = JSON.stringify(game["id"])
                // if game in cart === game in DB
                if (cartGameId === dbGameId) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(game))

                    // save new order with those games
                    const order = await DataStore.save(
                        new Order({
                            "customerName": "NewCustomer",
                            "customerAddress": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                            **"games": dbGameId**
                        })
                    );

                    **const gameOrder = await DataStore.save(
                        new GameOrder({
                            game: dbGameId,
                            order: order.id
                        })**
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

GraphQL schema (as generated by AWS Amplify):

```
type Game @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: owner}, {allow: private, provider: iam}, {allow: public, operations: [read]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["Admins"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  Name: String
  Price: Float
  Orders: [Order] @manyToMany(relationName: "GameOrder")
}

type Order @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]) {
  id: ID!
  customerName: String
  customerAddress: String
  games: [Game] @manyToMany(relationName: "GameOrder")
  Games: [String]
}
```

[The DynamoDB GameOrder table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbxsZ.png)

[The DynamoDB Game table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IRHa.png)

No game attribute in Order table:
[DynamoDB Order attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xJvk.png)

I have tried the above. I have tried to send data to JUST the order table (successfully), I have queried the Game table (successfully), and I have compared the ID in the cart to the ID of the game in the Game table successfully. I have tried to then send the Game ID from the Game table and the Order ID from the Order table to the GameOrder table (GameID and OrderID are the partition keys for the join table).

[AWS Documentation for many-to-many relationships that I have been referencing](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#many-to-many-relationship)